# Mess up with Phoenix Reverb

Tags: dialogue, reverb, altiverb

I usually use Altiverb for dialogue premix, recently I bought Phoenix and R2 reverb due to their good reputation. However, I find them difficult to config. They have so many presets but none can satisfied me. For example, I want a normal living room for a home scene, there are so many presets of living room in Phoenix Reverb, but they all sound unnatural and 'too much reverb', compare with the same level of aux send with altiverb. I try to adjust the setting of Phoenix but can get a good result. Did I miss some thing with Phoenix?

Comment: Interesting observation. I've had a similar experience with Phoenixverb ie. there are so many presets but seldom do I find one that "works" right away.

Comment: You too??For me, Phoenix is good at Hall/Chamber, but it is difficult to create a living room or bathroom.

Comment: Especially for some scenes with high ceiling, what Phoenix gives me is just more reverb.

Comment: As a counterpoint to my previous comment, I used a large hall setting in Phoenix today and found that it had a beautiful blooming effect that I've not heard in Altiverb before. If sounded very natural and fit just right.

Comment: any one can share experiences with Phoenix reverb?